# Item matching with domain knowlege

Tags: language-agnostic, nlp, string-matching

I have various product items that I need to decide if they are the same. A quick example:

`Microsoft RS400 mouse with middle button` should match `Microsoft Red Style 400 three buttoned mouse` but not `Microsoft Red Style 500 mouse`

There isn't anything else nice that I can match with apart from the name and just doing it on the ratio of matching words isn't good enough (The error rate is far too high)

I do know about the domain and so I can (for example) hand write the fact that a three buttoned mouse is probably the same as a mouse with a middle button. I also know the manufacturers (or can take a very good guess at them).

The only thought I have had so far is matching them by trying to use hand written rules to reduce the size of the string and then checking the matching words, but I wondered if anyone had any ideas best way of doing this matching was with a better accuracy and precision (or where to start looking) and if anyone knew of any work that had been done in this area? (papers, examples etc).

Answer (score 2):

> "I do know about the domain..."

How much *exactly* do you know about the domain?  If you know everything about the domain, then you might be better off building an index of all your manufacturers products (basically the description of the product from the manufacturers webpage).  Then instead of trying to match your descriptions to each other, matching them to your index of products.

Advantages to this approach:

- presumably all words used in the description of the product have been used somewhere in the promotional literature
- if when building the index you were able to weight some of the information (such as product codes) then you may have more success

Disadvantages:

- may take a long time to create the index (especially if done by hand)

---

If you don't know everything about your domain, then you might consider down-ranking words that are very common (you can get lists of common words off the internet), and up-ranking numbers and words that aren't in a dictionary (you can get lists of words off the internet/most linux/unix distributions come with them for spell checking purposes).

---

I don't know how much you know about search, but in the past I've found the book "Search Engines: Information Retrieval in Practice" by W. Bruce Croft, Donald Metzler, Trevor Strohman to be useful.  There are some sample chapters in the publishers website which will tell you if the book's for you or not: [pearsonhighered.com](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/croft1epreview/index.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: The downside is there are far too many items and they change too often for me to be bothered manually building an index of manufactureres items. The weighting of words sounds like a good idea. I may try an implementation using that method. And I will take a look at that book.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to hand-written rules, you may try to use supervised learning with feature extraction.

Let features be the words in description, than look on descriptions as feature vectors.
When teaching the algorithm, let it show you two vectors that look similar by the ratio, and if it's same item, let the algorithm improve weighs for those words.

For example, each pair of words may have bigger weight than simple ratio, as you have done.

```
[3-button]    [middle]
[wheel]       [button]
[mouse]       [mouse]
```

By your algorithm, it'll give ratio of 1/3 to similarity. When you set this as "same item" algorithm should add more value to those pair of words, when it reaches them next time.

Answer (score 1):

Just tokenize (you should seperate numbers from letters in that step aswell, so not just a whitespace tokenizer), stem, filter stopwords and uninteresting words like mouse. Perhaps you should have a list with words producers aswell and shorten all not producers and numbers to their first letter. (if you do that, you have to seperate capital letters aswell in the tokenizer)

```
Microsoft RS400 mouse with middle button -> Microsoft R S 400
Microsoft Red Style 400 three buttoned mouse -> Microsoft R S 400
Microsoft Red Style 500 mouse -> Microsoft R S 500
```

If you want a better solution
vsm (vector space model) out of plagiarism detection would be nice. (Every word gets a weight, according to their discriminative value and those weights are projected into a multidimensional space. After that you just measure the angular degree between 2 texts)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something a lot more generally applicable. As I understand it, you want some nlp processing that will deal with things that you recognize as synonyms. I think that's a pretty simple implementation right there.

If I were you I would make a keyword object that had a list of synonyms as a parameter, then write a script that would scrape whatever text you have for words that only appear occasionally (have some capped frequency at which the keyword is actually considered applicable), then add a list of keywords as a parameter of each keyword that contains it's synonyms. If you were willing to go a step further I would set weights on the synonym list showing how similar they are.

With this kind of nlp problem, the chance that you will get to 100% accuracy is 0, but you could well get above 90%, I would suggest adding an element by which you can adjust the weights in an automated way. I have to be fairly vague here, but in my last job I was tasked with a similar problem, and was able to get accuracy in the high 90's. My implementation was also probably more complicated than what you need, but even a simple implementation should get you pretty good return, but if you aren't dealing with a fairly large data set (~hundreds+) it's probably not worth scripting.

Quick example, in your example the difference can be distilled pretty accurately to just saying that "middle" and "three" are synonyms. You can get more complex if you need to, but that would match a lot.